# Where can I find the name of my app within the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This seems to be a simple question, but I am trying to setup a custom domain for my Google App Rngine. However, the custom domain seems to be stuck on "Google-managed, auto-renewing".

I saw I could use the following API call to find out what the current status is:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.authorizedCertificates/get

It says it wants the name of the App Engine I am looking at:

[image]

Does anyone know where I can find this name parameter within app engine? I've tried looking in the dashboard, versions, etc. but I can't find where this name tag is?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found it... it's under versions then you click on the version, then you click on one of the tabs on the right side and it shows you the name...